# LMV431 to generate negative voltage

Tags: voltage, negative, tl431

can someone show me how to use LMV431 to generate -1.24 V from -5V?

below is how I use it for positive.

Thank you
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this: -

[image]

It should be fairly self explanatory but, if you can't follow it use a simulator and see for yourself.